# spring-mvc with resteasy character encoding problem on jetty server

Tags: spring-mvc, character-encoding, jetty, maven-3, resteasy

I am trying to implement restful protocol on jetty server. I have runnable server and i can access it from my rest client. My server side project is a maven project. I have a problem about the character encoding.When i check response, before send it from controller, there is no encoding problem. But after i return response to client, i see broken data. Response header  is UTF-8. Also i have a listener for this problem and i am setting to request and response to UTF-8. I guess problem happens when i try to write my response data to response.

```
@GET
@Path("/")
@Produces({"application/xml;charset=UTF-8","application/json;charset=UTF-8"})
public String getPersons(@Context HttpServletRequest request, @Context HttpServletResponse response) {

    List<Person> persons = personService.getPersons(testUserId, collectionOption, null);
    if (persons == null) {
        persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
    }

    String result = JsonUtil.listToJson(persons);
    //result doesnt has any encoding problem at this line

    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setContentLength(result.length());
    response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");

    //i guess problem happen after this line
    return result;
}
```

Is there any jetty configuration or resteasy configuration for it? Or is there any way to solve this problem? Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 0):

Which resteasy version are you using? There is a known issue ([RESTEASY-467](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RESTEASY-467)) with Strings in 2.0.1 an prior.

These are your options:

1) force the encoding returning byte[]

```
public byte[] getPersons
```

and then

```
return result.getBytes("UTF8");
```

2) return List (or create a PersonListing if you need it)

```
public List<Person> getPersons
```

and let resteasy handle the json transformation.

3) return a StreamingOutput

NOTE: with this option the "Content-Length" header will be unknown.

```
return new StreamingOutput()
{

    public void write(OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException
    {
        PrintStream writer = new PrintStream(outputStream, true, "UTF-8");
        writer.println(result);
    }
};
```

4) upgrade to 2.2-beta-1 or newer version.

Comment: First option is not acceptable for me because i can say my client is dummy. For second option, i cant use it also because i have to convert person object2json myself. So it is still unsolved problem for me. Thanks for your options.

Comment: What do you mean by "my client is dummy"?

Comment: I've added two more options. I don't think there is any other option left.

Comment: thanks for your answer. First three options are not useful for me. Because my result type has to string. i failed to run my server with 2.2-beta-1, i guess jetty 6.1.24 and resteasy 2.2-beta-1 are not compatible. i am working on this problem. if i success to run server i can see the 4th option result.

Comment: if your problem is this expcetion `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.xml.stream.ZephyrParserFactory cannot be cast to org.codehaus.stax2.XMLInputFactory2`. Add this to your system properties: `javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory=com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory`. See: http://tynamo.org/tapestry-resteasy+guide#tapestry-resteasyguide-Notes%3A